# Setting an AudioUnit's SampleRate to 16000 Hz without using an AudioSession

Tags: iphone, ios, audiounit

I would like to request a 16k Hz sample rate without using an audio session, but have thus far not been successful.

Querying the hardware via AudioUnitGetProperty / SampleRate before configuring the mic / speakers reveals an mSampleRate of 0, which is described in the documentation as implying that any sample rate is supported, but it is also stated that the hardware will actually give you the nearest one that it supports. After I request 16k and query the hardware again the mSampleRate is 44100 for both mic and speakers respectively. Querying the input/output scope of the input/output busses using AudioUnitGetProperty / SampleRate returns 0 in all cases, as does using the equivalent query with StreamFormat instead. Querying with AudioSessionGetProperty / CurrentHardwareSampleRate, despite the session not being configured or initialized, returns 44100. Everything works as expected when using an audio session, but this is not described as necessary in the documentation, except for submitting to the app store which I am not doing.

It is also not clear to me whether, when using an audio session and requesting 16k Hz, the session quietly converts to 16k between the input and output scopes of the input bus, or whether the hardware does actually support "any" sample rate as mentioned in the documentation. It would also be nice to have a list of sample rates supported by the hardware - it's hard to understand why there isn't a queryable list.

I'm interested in any relevant documentation that describes how to do this (without a session), or explains exactly which sample rates I can set the output scope of the input bus to. I have seen discussion in various threads here that it must be a downshift of 44.1k, but I have thus far not found any documentation supporting that assertion.

Many thanks.